# How to upload binary content octetstream in Alfresco by RestSharp?

Tags: c#, alfresco, restsharp

I try put binary file through restful api alfresco, It worked, it has content when i edit text file but that pdf file can't preview, may be the content's encoding is not true? Any one has solution? I use restSharp to do this

```
IRestRequest requestPutContentFile = new RestRequest(APILocation._CORE_API + "/nodes/" + docNode.Entry.Id + "/content"+"?alf_ticket="+Ticket,Method.PUT);
requestPutContentFile.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", Content, ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse responsePutContentFile = client.Execute(requestPutContentFile);
```

https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#!/nodes/updateNodeContent

/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/{nodeId}/content

[image]

Comment: What does the Node Browser show for the new node?

Answer (score 0):

Preview does not work for PDF, but does work for text?

Most probably the problem lies with the the mimetype of the uploaded content, and available transformers for it.

Like @Gagravarr suggested, take a look in Node Browser what you have for mimetype ("cm:content") property, have a look at the log looking for transformation errors, and have a look at supported transformations.

http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/mimetypes